# radio button show and hide div 2

Tags: jquery

I have 2 radio buttons.
When I click on one of them new div appear.
I want it to disappear when I choose the second button.

Thank you in advanced.

```
<p><label>Type</label><input type='radio' name='affType' value='private' class='short_filed' checked /> Private <input type='radio' name='affType' value='company' class='short_filed return'/> Company</p>

<div class="hidden">
    <p><label>Name</label><input type='text' name='companyName' value=''  /></p>
</div>


<script>
$(".hidden").hide(400);
$('.return').change(function(){
   if(this.checked){
      $('.hidden').show( "slide", 400);
   }else{
      $('.hidden').hide( "slide", 400);
   }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**WORKING FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2q6SB/)

```
$(".hidden").hide(400);
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'company'){
      $('.hidden').show();
   }else{
      $('.hidden').hide();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the logic, because you're only ever checking if the checkbox is checked, not its actual value.

Also, change your selector, since you're only listening to the `change` event on the second radio button:

```
$(".hidden").hide(400);
$('input[name="affType"]').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == 'company'){
      $('.hidden').show();
   }else{
      $('.hidden').hide();
   }
});
```

[<kbd>**jsFiddle Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/EY4HA/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change JQuery script as like below... Or try this **[JSFiddle LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/kauH9/1/)**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.short_filed').bind('change',function () {
            $('.hidden').toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

If you need to Hide and Show textbox on only company radio button selection and deselection then follow below code...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.return').bind('change',function () {
                $('.hidden').toggle();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: And set `.hidden{display:none;}` in CSS file

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify it to:

```
$('input.short_filed').change(function() {
    $('.hidden').toggle( this.checked && this.value == 'company' );
}).filter(':checked').change();
```

So it's checking the state of the checkbox, and the value, then toggling `.hidden` based on the result of that.

The `.filter(':checked').change()` will trigger the `change()` event on the checked checkbox when the page loads, so you don't need to call `('.hidden').hide()/show()`.

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SfJ7R/9/)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the below code sample :

```
<p>
    <label>Type</label><input type='radio' name='affType' value='private' class='short_filed' checked />
    Private
    <input type='radio' name='affType' id="radComp" value='company' class='short_filed return' />
    Company</p>

<div class="hidden" style="display: none">
    <p>
        <label>Name</label><input type='text' name='companyName' value=''  /></p>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $('input[type = radio]').change(function () {
        if (this.value == "company") {
            $('.hidden').show("slide", 400);

        } else {
            $('.hidden').hide("slide", 400);
        }
    });
</script>
```